# Nested If Else statement Quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, if-statement, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to create a calculated field based on the condition of a field not being blank. So I am using ifelse(isNULL(State2) OR State2 = '', {email}). I am trying to do the same thing for phone number but I need another if else statement for pulling the phone number - ifelse(agentmobilephone = '',agentofficephone, agentmobilephone). Is there a way to combine the ifelse for the state as well as the ifelse for the phone number?